# couchDB conflicts when supplying own ID with large inserts using _bulk_docs

Tags: node.js, couchdb, es6-promise, axios

Same code works fine when letting couch auto generate UUID's. I am starting off with a new completely empty database yet I keep getting this

```
error: conflict 
reason: Document update conflict
```

To reiterate I am posting new documents to an empty database so not sure how I can get update conflicts when nothing is being updated. Even stranger the conflicting documents still show up in the DB with only a single revision, but overall there are missing records.

I am trying to insert about 38,000 records with _bulk_docs in batches of 100. I am getting these records (100 at a time) from a RETS server, each record already has a unique ID that I want to use for the couchDB _id instead of their UUID's. I am using a promised based library to get the records and axios to insert them into couch. After getting the first batch of 100 I then run this code to add an _id to each of the 100 records before inserting

```
let batch = [];
batch = records.results.map((listing) => {
     let temp = listing;
     temp._id = listing.ListingKey;
     return temp;
});
```

Then insert:

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5984/rets_store/_bulk_docs', { docs: batch })
```

This is all inside of a function that I call recursively.

I know this probably wont be enough to see the issue but thought Id start here. I know for sure it has something to do with my map() and adding the _id = ListingKey

Thanks!

Comment: Your `map` looks fine, best guess is that your `records.results` are overlapping in different batches for some reason.

Comment: @smathy yea I think I might be hammering couchdb with to many inserts to fast. I changed from bulk_docs to looping through each record and inserting one at a time but I get the same result. Also the records with conflicts are 100% random and never the same. DO you know if axios and/or couch should be able to handle this many records and if not what the standard way of inserting bulk data would be.

Comment: These are not the symptoms of an overloaded server.  I didn't mean an overlap in time, that's not a problem for couch, I meant an overlap in IDs.  Like the same `listing.ListingKey` is being pulled in two separate batches.

Comment: That is the issue I just cant figure out why. I rewrote the function so it just loops through the batch adding the _id and inserting them one by one but I still have the same issues. When console logging the loop to show the _id when it is added and then another log within the axios.post() (all within a single iteration of the loop) it spits out all the ID's in a row then all of the "Done"s after? I am assuming this is to do with my promise handling, I think I'm going to have to reword this question as I dont even know what Im asking anymore. lol

Comment: ...and in what is printed out you can't see an ID that was already printed earlier in your loop?